# Is there a clean way to get bidirectional grub-reboot without a shared boot partition?

Tags: linux, grub

I've got grub2 in my SSD's MBR, with three distros sharing 3/4 of a logical partition, along with a shared home partition. There is no boot partition; all three distros have their own /boot directory on their own partitions. grub is governed by Manjaro.

Consequently, I can grub-reboot from Manjaro into another system, but not from either of the other distros (nor from Windows, but I'm not even inclined to try without a dedicated boot partition.)

As I see it, my options include:

- Create a boot partition, with all its dangers
- Mount Manjaro in my other distros, at some odd mount point like /mnt/manjaro_root, and use symlinks to redirect the other distros' grub-reboot output to Manjaro's
- That's all I've got

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Are you asking how to make it work with `grub-reboot` specifically or are you open to alternatives such as manually selecting a boot entry in the Grub menu...?

Comment: I'm asking how to make it work with `grub-reboot` specifically.